# I mistakenly purged gsettings-desktop-schemas; how can I recover?

Tags: lightdm, mate, recovery-mode

Here's how things went from bad to worse:

I wanted to remove an item (an icon) on the Unity-greeter top panel. (The greeter is the only Unity thing I use). So I made some changes in one of the Unity-greeter config files, or lightdm config files (I forget which). This left me in low-graphics mode.

Then, I stupidly and accidentally ran this command:`sudo apt-get purge gsettings-desktop-schemas && apt-get install gsettings-desktop-schemas`

Then I watched tons of things being purged. Then I had no online connectivity, and still don't, from my Ubuntu Mate 14.04 drive. I also appear to have no backup of my 14.04.

I can -- from my Ubuntu Mate 16.04 disk -- mount the drive that has 14.04 on it and access it that way. My question:

How can I:

(a) get back online;

(b) recover gsettings-desktop-schemas;

and (c) get lightdm/unity-greeter running back in graphics mode?

Would it make any sense for me to try to copy my 16.04 (or 12.04) "gsettings-desktop-schemas" over to the 14.04 system? (though I don't know where to look for it).

I really seem to have wandered into no-man's-land, & need to get on the right path. Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Boot to your damaged Mate 14.04, connect it using network cable.
2. When you reach low graphic message, switch to virtual console tty1 using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd>.
3. Login then run `ifconfig` check you network interface name.

   ```
   ~$ ifconfig 
   eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr f2:11:df:ff:59:0c  
             UP BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
             RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
             TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
             collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
             RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)
             Interrupt:20 Memory:f7e00000-f7e20000
   ```

   If you can't see any, use `ifconfig -a` instead, then enable it using `sudo ifup eth0`.

   Use the name you got to auto configure it using DHCP.

   ```
   sudo dhclient eth0
   ```
4. To check connection

   ```
   ~$ ping google.com
   PING google.com (216.58.208.238) 56(84) bytes of data.
   64 bytes from par10s22-in-f14.1e100.net (216.58.208.238): icmp_seq=1 ttl=54 time=57.5 ms
   64 bytes from par10s22-in-f14.1e100.net (216.58.208.238): icmp_seq=2 ttl=54 time=59.8 ms
   ```
5. Fix the desktop by reinstall all missing packages

   ```
   sudo apt-get install mate-desktop
   ```
6. Reboot

You are done!

Comment: Thank you!  I'll give it a whirl late tonight.  Would anyone know which log will show me everything that was purged when I ran that command?

Comment: @MelvinQ.Watchpocket, yes sure here a ready command `zmore /var/log/dpkg.log* | grep -e " purge " -e " remove " -e "install " | sort > ~/Desktop/dpkg-histroy-$(date -I).txt` . If you want to see in details remove the grep filter.

Comment: ~$ ifconfig only showed "lo   Link encap:Local loopback inet addr: ... Mask ... UP LOOPBACK RUNING [etc]"  but no "eth0" or "eth1"  -- i.e., I'm not able to connect from there.

Comment: @MelvinQ.Watchpocket, and  `ifconfig -a` ?

Comment: **ifconfig -a** does show me the info for **eth0**, **lo** and **wlan0**.  But invoking _**sudo dhclient eth0**_ does nothing. . . .

Comment: @MelvinQ.Watchpocket may be it is off , switch on using `sudo ifup eth0`  then `sudo dhclient eth0`

Comment: I take that back!  After running **ifconfig -a** I was in fact able to connect to the online repository with the _**sudo dhclient eth0**_ command. (I mean, with  _**sudo apt-get update**_  and so on.) I can now from here either try to restore the whole honkin' heft of lost packages or else just reinstall my Mate OS.  Thanks for the intel!